# "app:validateSigningRelease" error after saving the Gradle variables in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

While creating the AAB, I want to save the Keystore information in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties as described in the RN document (Pic 1). I created the gradle.properties file as seen below and entered the values (Pic 2). But when I get the release build I get the following error. I guess it can't access these values. Other than adding these values here, what else do I need to do?

ps: If I write the values to android/gradle.properties file, I can get build without any problem. So I did the rest of the steps. The problem is just writing these values to ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

```
> Task :app:validateSigningRelease FAILED

> Task :app:mergeExtDexRelease
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:mergeExtDexRelease' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'android/app/build/intermediates/duplicate_classes_check/release'. Reason: Task ':app:mergeExtDexRelease' uses this output of task ':app:copyReleaseBundledJs' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'android/app/build/intermediates/external_file_lib_dex_archives/release'. Reason: Task ':app:mergeExtDexRelease' uses this output of task ':app:copyReleaseBundledJs' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file not set for signing config release
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've forgotten to add below code in app level build.gradle

```
android{
   signingConfigs {       
          release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I write the values to android/gradle.properties file, I can get build without any problem. So I did the rest of the steps. The problem is just writing these values to ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

Comment: From provided screenshot, you can add values to ~/.gradle/gradle.properties **or** android/gradle.properties.

and if you want to add in  ~/.gradle/gradle.properties, you may have to do below step  
**Saving the above Gradle variables in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties instead of android/gradle.properties prevents them from being checked in to git. You may have to create the ~/.gradle/gradle.properties file in your user's home directory before you can add the variables.**
  
Official Doc [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android#setting-up-gradle-variables)

Comment: "You may have to create the ~/.gradle/gradle.properties file in your user's home directory before you can add the variables." Didn't I do this in the second photo? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, and it appears that the problem arises from creating the `.gradle` properties file within the project's directory. To resolve this, you'll need to create the file in your user's home directory instead.

Here are the steps to accomplish this if you're using macOS:

1. Open your terminal and navigate to your home directory by typing `cd ~`. Alternatively, , you can access the home directory through
   Finder.

   2. Once in your home directory, run the command `touch ~/.gradle/gradle.properties`. This will create the necessary
      `.gradle` directory and `gradle.properties` file within your home
      directory. Alternatively, you can create .gradle`directory in your home directory and create a file named`gradle.properties`within the`.gradle` directory manually using finder options.
   3. Now, open the `gradle.properties` file for editing. You can use the terminal by typing `nano ~/.gradle/gradle.properties`.
      Alternatively, you can open it with any code editor, such as Visual
      Studio Code.
   4. Add the necessary Gradle variables to the `gradle.properties` file and save your changes.

By following these steps, you should be able to resolve the issue you encountered.